# Adding product variations using the configurable product module

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, programmatically

I have issues creating configurable product using the configurable product and EAV modules.

Here is what I currently do :

```
    // $product is a simple product created before

    $product->setTypeId('configurable');
    $this->_productRepository->save($product);

    $versionAttribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get(4, 'product-version');

    $configurableOption = $this->_configurableOptionFactory->create();
    $configurableOption->setLabel('Version');
    $configurableOption->setAttributeId($versionAttribute->getId());
    $configurableOption->setProductId($product->getId());

    $configurableOptionValues = [];
    foreach ($versions as $version)
    {
        // Just creates a clone of the default attribute set, adding the 'version' attribute
        $versionAttributeSet = getOrCreateVersionAttributeSet();

        $option = $this->_attributeOptionFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($version['name']);
        $this->_attributeOptionManagement->add(4, 'product_version', $option);

        $configurableOptionValue = $this->_configurableOptionValueFactory->create();

        // Set the value index to the value of the created option (not pretty sure about this)
        $configurableOptionValue->setValueIndex($option->getValue());

        $configurableOptionValues[] = $configurableOptionValue;
    }

    $configurableOption->setValues($configurableOptionValues);
    $this->_configurableProductManagement->generateVariation($product, array($configurableOption));

    return $product;
```

For information, here is the factories used :

```
\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\AttributeFactory $configurableOptionFactory
\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionValueInterfaceFactory $configurableOptionValueFactory
\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $attributeOptionFactory
```

And here is the exception issued :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Attribute with attributeCode "5183" does not exist.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Attribute with attributeCode "5183" does not exist.
#0 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Repository.php(90): Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository->get('catalog_product', '5183')
#1 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Repository/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository->get('5183')
#2 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ConfigurableProductManagement.php(89): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository\Interceptor->get('5183')
#3 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ConfigurableProductManagement.php(51): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableProductManagement->getAttributesForMatrix(Array)
#4 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/app/code/MyModule/Import/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Load.php(1099): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableProductManagement->generateVariation(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#5 /var/www/mymagentosite.com/app/code/MyModule/Import/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Load.php(1291): MyModule\Import\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Load->createConfigurableProduct(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
```